# Narrowing types using switch statement does not work on a generic type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to narrow down an enum value and return a different instance of a class depending on the enum value.

Why does the switch case works when not using generics?

On example 1, I am trying to narrow down a generic type which extends an enum. However it still errors when I use switch cases.

On example 2, narrowing down a enum type directly does not cause an error.

Is there any reasoning behind this?

```js
class ReportA {
   constructor(public type: ReportType.A) { }
}

class ReportB {
   constructor(public type: ReportType.B) { }
}

enum ReportType {
   A = "A",
   B = "B"
}

/** Example 1. Does not work... Why? */
class ReportFactory<Type extends ReportType> {
   constructor(public type: Type) { }

   public create = () => {
      switch (this.type) {
         case ReportType.A: {
            /** ERROR! */
            return new ReportA(this.type)
         }
         case ReportType.B: {
            /** ERROR! */
            return new ReportB(this.type)
         }
         default: throw new Error()
      }
   }
}

/** Example 2. Works */
class ReportFactory2 {
   constructor(public type: ReportType) { }
 
   public create = () => {
      switch (this.type) {
         case ReportType.A: {
            /** WORKS! */
            return new ReportA(this.type)
         }
         case ReportType.B: {
            /** WORKS! */
            return new ReportB(this.type)
         }
         default: throw new Error()
      }
   }
}
```

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmAHA9gJwC4EFoG8BQ0hwyAdhOqgK7DpoAUilARiAJbDToCei8AXHCRp0AFR7wAdJgCUuaAF88ivKEgwEKDACFcBIqXJUa9Ri3adxAjcLG8JW2TgVK8eeCUoBbQZtHjdhNDYALzQAESYYQA0etA6oWFaYS54APQAVOnQAKIAHmCeiCDw0ACMEtAAIsjwMCTI6NAA7mgA1hId0ADqABZcAPzQ6akq4FA+wgBiYMaoXAA8tiXwuejuACbqQhhLAHwB+mQU1LSoDMxsHNy8AkuOzrGml9DAqPBga9ChdLLB+-iBQIQJqsdDAHrQOjoHqsCASa7wRyxQFESAlaw7cRSAQAlF4jJZbKwWAAeVgAEIhiM8Xi3uhKKgSNASPAmhMMJgoTC4QjpMiUYoaaiIOjtn47FocfyaQScsSyZThtLafB6Yzmaz2egtFzYfDxHyhc4jet4AAzMCUEDoATQ1DINkstnZVD2s6GgWxRTKWV5ApFEoAJgqXTaMCVqnGGPQ01mXEDBxeBmOs3OZiuli1dzkykCT3Mr3en2+v3+0uBoPBkOhet5ibxwDRWaxmClRsCsq6ZIA0gBlRXU9vQOkMplOrWcms8g3KwiCoWNkXNiVtoednv9qmzwEj9Xj6M6qf63gemnzmmmi1Wm2cHr2x2al1un7S8-eoA)

Comment: FWIW, it would be clearer if `ReportFactory2` were also a `class` so the **only** difference was the generic parameter, something like this: https://pastebin.com/iPYXqCF7 Re the actual problem, though, I don't get why TypeScript isn't allowing that -- probably has to do with `extends` but... You can of course just use a literal value (`case ReportType.A: { /** Works now */ return new ReportA(ReportType.A) } `) but the duplication between the case label and the argument is irritating and (to my mind) a maintenance issue... :-|

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the suggestion. I have edited my examples with it.

Comment: Seems related https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995) from TypeScript. Thanks [@Yury Tarabanko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65000421/narrowing-types-using-switch-statement-does-not-work-on-a-generic-type?noredirect=1#comment114921065_65000421) for linking.

Seemingly the only solution for me is cast the type or use `// @ts-ignore` comment.

```js
new ReportA(this.type as ReportType.A)
// @ts-ignore
new ReportA(this.type)
```

Comment: Better try using TypeScript guards https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types